# How do I move the title a bit to the right?

Tags: html, alignment

I have aligned my text to that it is central, however because of a navigation bar it is slightly to the left of center. How do I adjust the position of it ever so slightly?

This is the title code:

```html
<div id="header">
<u><h1 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1><u>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `position:relative`?

Answer (score 1):

Setup the padding-left parameter. Here an example with 50 pixels to the right:

```html
<div id="header">
<u><h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;padding-left:50px; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1><u>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-left` to increase the leading space, which shifts it over to the right:

```css
h1 {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <u><h1 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1></u>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use text-indent or padding-left.

```
<div id="header">
<u><h1 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-indent: 5px; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1><u>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
<div id="header">
<u><h1 style="padding-left: 20px; font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1><u>
</div>
```

You can play with the padding-left value to get the result you want.